# Load Application on to external display

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

I have connected one external Display to my laptop( means connected one HDMI display) which contains Ubuntu 16.04 as the OS. I would like to display content like VLC player, Firefox etc on the external display using command line interface. Tried with DISPLAY command but didn't succeeded.

Could someone help me on this

Comment: Isn't unchecking `Mirror displays` in Display settings sufficient? why do you require a command line solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have read somewhere,
"connect your TV to your computer and type into a terminal the following command:
'xrandr --output TMDS-1 --auto'
you should see your computer screen on your TV after that. You still might have to adjust your resolution (System>Preferences>Display) ....I have to set mine to 1024x768
It that works you can just build a Launcher with those settings to automate"

hope this will help you.
[ref](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1425680)